# Dependency injection error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am getting **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]** in a very strange manner.

If I inject dependency in this manner it throws the above error.

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('myRoutes', ['ngRoute']);
 app.config(['$routeProvider'], function ($routeProvider) {

  });
```

But if I flip the above snippet in the below way, the error is gone.

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('myRoutes', ['ngRoute']);

 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    //no error
 });
```

I am using Angular v 1.3.1

Scripts including order.

- angular.js
- angular-routes.js
- myroutes.js
- myCtrl.js

Considering the minification in production environment, I can't go with the second way.

Answer (score 3):

You have not closed config `inline array annotation` function correctly

```
app.config(['$routeProvider'], function ($routeProvider) {
```

should be

```
//                     VVVVVVVVVV removed  `]`
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

}]); //<-- close it here
```

Comment: That happens, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close it right.

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('myRoutes', ['ngRoute']);
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

 }]);
```

The recommended way of doing this is using the array notation.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di